# Excel VBA Webquey creates new column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-web-query

for example, following query will create a new column **A** and the data from **A** column will now be in Column **B**

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & u, _
Destination:=Cells(14, 8))
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
End With
```

is it possible that the destination of web query remain fixed lets say **A1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add `.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells` inside your With clause. This will force the external data to A1 instead of adding a new column.

Comment: i have updated the code you can see above, however it is still not working excel always inserts a new column

Comment: I suggest you add only that one row to your previous code. also change destination property to range($A$1). it worked for me on excel 2010. no column was added, the new data overwrites whatever is on cell a1